# multiple images in a single frame in opencv

Tags: opencv, image-processing, video-processing, video-capture, color-space

I extracted a video from a VHS tape.  The horizontal sync didn't trigger properly in many of the lines causing that line to be shifted, usually to the right.  I wrote some code in an attempt to detect the black left edge and shift frames.  That mostly worked, but some frames look like they consist of two images.

[image: frame with multiple images]

Notice that the speaker's hair appears to have two exposures; one which has a horizontal shift and another that doesn't.  Is this a problem with the video capture device?  Do you know of any mitigation?  I wouldn't mind paying for software instead of rolling my own.

I don't think important to the question, but this is the code that I'm using per frame in the hope that it will be of use to others.  Really just a piecing together of SO code and Bing AI.

```py
def apply_shift(img, column_shifts):
    "Once a left-right shift is established per row, apply and pad with the last pixel"
    rolled = np.empty_like(img)
    for i in range(img.shape[0]):
        rolled[i] = np.roll(img[i], column_shifts[i], axis=0)
    # Replace the rolled values with the end value of each row
    for i in range(img.shape[0]):
        if column_shifts[i] > 0:
            rolled[i, :column_shifts[i]] = rolled[i, column_shifts[i]]
        elif column_shifts[i] < 0:
            rolled[i, column_shifts[i]:] = rolled[i, column_shifts[i]]
    return rolled

def add_counter_to_frame(frame, counter):

    img = Image.fromarray(frame)
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
    font = ImageFont.load_default()
    draw.text((350, 50), f"{counter}", fill='black', font=font)
    return np.array(img)

G_frame_counter:int = 0
def straighten_frame(frame):
    global G_frame_counter
    G_frame_counter += 1
    frame = add_counter_to_frame(frame, G_frame_counter)
    gray = np.dot(frame[...,:3], [0.2989, 0.5870, 0.1140])
    threshold = 75   # (from 0 to 255)
    wanted_pixel_at_threshold = 4 # Force all scan lines to have their threshold crossing at this pixel
    max_shift = 4 # Shift no more than max_shift pixels
    clean_sigma = 2
    indices = np.argmax(gray > threshold, axis=1)
    shift_amount = wanted_pixel_at_threshold-indices
    shift_amount[shift_amount < -max_shift] = -max_shift
    shift_amount[shift_amount > max_shift] = max_shift
    cleaned_shift_amount = gaussian_filter(shift_amount, sigma=clean_sigma)
    rolled = apply_shift(frame, cleaned_shift_amount)
    return rolled
```

Comment: color spaces. luma and chroma are misaligned to each other.

Comment: oh and there would have been interlaced signal, and I'm guessing you didn't disable some kind of bad deinterlacing, so now you've got this trashed data. -- basically, you can throw the code away and re-digitize the video, but make sure to figure out all the settings that mess with the data in ways that can't be undone.